updating SCTLR_EL1 register not working in bare-matel ARMv8 program on QEMU
I am learning armv8 assembly program for my project. I wrote a simple program which tries to modify value of SCTLR_EL1 register. Unfortunately this code is not working. I am enabling I-cache, but the only thing I see is 0x0 in SCTLR_EL1.
.section .text
.global _start

_start:
    mov x0, xzr                 // Initialize x0 to zero
    // Set SCTLR_EL1 and confirm the modification
    mrs x0, SCTLR_EL1            // Read SCTLR_EL1 into x0
    orr x0, x0, #(1 << 12)       // Enable I-Cache
    msr SCTLR_EL1, x0            // Write back to SCTLR_EL1

    mrs x0, SCTLR_EL1            // Read the modified SCTLR_EL1 into x0
    // Store the value in a known memory location for debugging
    ldr x1, =sctlr_el1_val
    str x0, [x1]

    b loop

loop:
    b loop

.data
.align 8
sctlr_el1_val: .quad 0x0100        // Memory location to store the SCTLR_EL1 value

memmap
MEMORY
{
    rom  : ORIGIN = 0x00010000, LENGTH = 32K
}

SECTIONS
{
   .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
}

QEMU command used is as follows:
qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt -cpu cortex-a57 -m 512M -nographic -machine secure=on \
-S -s -kernel path_to_your_binary.elf -d in_asm,cpu

Output I see in console is:
PSTATE=000003cd ---- EL3h
 PC=0000000000000200 X00=0000000000000000 X01=0000000000000000
X02=0000000000000000 X03=0000000000000000 X04=0000000000000000
X05=0000000000000000 X06=0000000000000000 X07=0000000000000000
X08=0000000000000000 X09=0000000000000000 X10=0000000000000000
X11=0000000000000000 X12=0000000000000000 X13=0000000000000000
X14=0000000000000000 X15=0000000000000000 X16=0000000000000000
X17=0000000000000000 X18=0000000000000000 X19=0000000000000000
X20=0000000000000000 X21=0000000000000000 X22=0000000000000000
X23=0000000000000000 X24=0000000000000000 X25=0000000000000000
X26=0000000000000000 X27=0000000000000000 X28=0000000000000000
X29=0000000000000000 X30=0000000000000000  SP=0000000000000000
PSTATE=000003cd ---- EL3h

GDB did not show anything:
(gdb) x/x 0x0100
0x100:  0x00000000
(gdb) x/x $SCTLR_EL1
Value can't be converted to integer.
(gdb) p/x $SCTLR_EL1
$1 = void
(gdb) display  $SCTLR_EL1
1: $SCTLR_EL1 = void
(gdb)  p/x $CurrentEL
$2 = void

How can i modify CurrentEL and SCTLR_EL1? and how can I see those register value using GDB?
Can someone please help? Thank you.

It doesn't appear that you're actually inspecting the contents of  sctlr_el1_val. 0x100 isn't its address, it's the value with which you've initialized it. Try x sctlr_el1_val. I don't think gdb has a way to inspect those registers directly, so things like p/x $SCTLR_EL1 simply won't work.

That register dump from the console - at what point in your program is it generated? The register contents aren't consistent with it coming from the busy loop, which is where you would want to do it.

Also I think you have to use x/xg to see all 8 bytes.

Thanks for your response. the register dump in console is continuously printed. As suggested, i checked the mmory address, its still zero.
Symbol "sctlr_el1_val" is at 0x10100 in a file compiled without debugging.
(gdb) x/xg 0x10100
0x10100: 0x0000000000000000

That is definitely not the right cpu state dump given that x1 is supposed to be the address of sctlr_el1_val. You also did not show how you assemble and link. Anyway, it works here. X00=0000000000c51838 X01=0000000000011108

@Jester Edited my question to include makefile. Could you please let me know if you made any changes in code to make it work? how did you build it? Thanks

Works without -machine secure=on Not sure what that does. Also your linker script calls the area rom and .data is not mentioned. Might have something to do with it.

Unfortunately adding .data section didn't resolve the issue. Still same behaviour.

The QEMU output what you see is caused from an exception. As @Jester mentioned this is because you are enabling -machine secure=on. This option enables the ARM TrustZone extension. Use a higher program entry point address. An entry point at 0x40000000 should work.
You also have forgotten the isb instruction after writing to SCTLR_EL1. When you read directly SCTLR_EL1 after the write-back without isb instruction, the content from SCTLR_EL1 is the old one (content before msr SCTLR_EL1, x0).
.section .text
.func _start,_start
.type _start,%function
.global _start

_start:
    mov x0, xzr                 /* Initialize x0 to zero */
    mrs x0, SCTLR_EL1           /* Read SCTLR_EL1 into x0 */
    orr x0, x0, #(1 << 12)      /* Enable I-Cache */
    msr SCTLR_EL1, x0           /* Write back to SCTLR_EL1 */
    isb                         /* Instruction Synchronization barrier */

loop:
    b loop

.size _start, . - _start
.endfunc

To display the registers values with GDB you can use the command info registers or info all-registers. These should also include the SCTLR register.
CurrentEL can be extracted from the current program status register (cpsr) in the output from GDB.
For changing/switching to a lower exception levels there you can find enough samples here on SO on other sites.
